# Should I include <stdio.h> in my header file, just so I can declare a function that takes a FILE*?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, header-files, declaration

For example in `foo.h`:

```
typedef struct foo_t foo_t;

/* Lots of function declarations dealing with foo_t... */

int foo_print(const foo_t *foo); /* Print foo to stdout. */
int foo_fprint(FILE *f, const foo_t *foo); /* Print foo to file f. */
```

I don't want to litter `foo.h` with too many other header files that users of `foo.h` might not have wanted to include, but I do need to declare functions that take types such as `FILE*`. I doubt that I am the first to encounter this dilemma, so what do people usually do in these circumstances? Or am I misguided in wanting to avoid including `stdio.h` in my header files?

EDIT:

People seem not to be understanding my question. To clarify, here are some potential solutions:

1. Just include `stdio.h` and not worry about it causing conflicts in my clients' code (such as if they happened to have their own function that happened to be called `getchar`).
2. Use an `#ifdef` to find out if `stdio.h` had already been included, and only then declare the `FILE*`-related functions. The downside of this is that it would impose a particular ordering to `#include`s in my clients' code.
3. Move all I/O-related declarations to a separate header file such as `foo_io.h`.

What question is what is the *best* thing to do?

Comment: `I don't want to litter foo.h with too many other header files that users of foo.h might not have wanted to include`  So you want to put the burden on your clients to `#include <stdio.h>`, or else *your* code doesn't compile?  Your code should compile without "user intervention".

Comment: Problem is, there's no header that allows you to correctly forward declare `FILE` (and therefore be able to use a `FILE *` without including `stdio.h`), like there is for other I/O (`iosfwd`). So you must go with the include.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: No, my question was how *could* I deal with this problem. If I had already decided to burden my clients, I wouldn't have needed to ask this question. I could use `#ifdef`s that would then impose a particular inclusion order for the clients, which I also wouldn't want. This is what I'm asking about. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Wrt. the edited question: the correct answer is 1., or 3. if you worry about introducing tons of extra headers and names. An unconditional `#include <stdio.h>` should ***never*** be a problem for your clients. This is C: there are no namespacs. If you pick a name already present in the standard library **it's your fault**.

Comment: @peppe: "If you pick a name already present in the standard library it's your fault." Not if you don't mean to ever include the standard library in one particular source file.

Comment: Redefining an identifier defined in the standard library causes undefined behavior, whether the corresponding header is included or not. (This applies only for identifiers defined with external linkage; you *can* redefine them at block scope or with `static`, but it's still a bad idea.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: You are assuming that every programmer knows every identifier in the standard library.

Comment: @Matt: Unfortunately *ignorantia legis non excusat* :) If you're using C you abide by its rules, which include that you can't redefine anything defined by the standard library. So yes, a programmer should be very very wary at defining things. Why do you think every C library out there uses prefixing? (`X` for Xlib, `G` for Glib, `gl` for OpenGL...)

Comment: @Matt: If your client's code define its own `getchar()` function, then the client's code *has undefined behavior* regardless of what's in the header you provide. If your header causes that bug to be revealed, that's a good thing.

Comment: @KeithThompson: As you said yourself, not if it's `static`.

Comment: @Matt: Right -- and if it's `static`, then your header's `#include <stdio.h>` won't interfere with it.

Comment: @Matt: My apologies, my previous comment was not entirely correct. If the standard declaration of `getchar()` and a static declaration of `getchar` that's likely to be a compile-time error. (There's no link-time conflict because `static` functions have no linkage.) Still, I'd say it's not worth worrying about. If you need to use `FILE*`, you need to include `<stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you are trying to solve a non-existing problem.

If you use `FILE`, you include `stdio.h` or `cstdio` in C++. It's that simple.

Trying to "optimize" `#include`s, besides obvious cases of unused ones, will not buy you anything and cause problems.

Comment: Will buy compilation times on older compilers and/or in absence of precompiled headers.

Comment: ***Trying to "optimize" #includes, besides obvious cases of unused ones, will not buy you anything and cause problems.*** I think that depends on how long your builds take. I mean when your builds take 15+ minutes  you may want to spend some time optimizing this.

Comment: I never said anything about optimization.

Answer (score 2):

You should strive to have header files compile cleanly in an empty source module.  For example:

`#include "myheader.h"`

and that's it.  If you put that in a C++ source file and compiled it with no other code, you should get *no* compiler errors.

If you do get errors, then you need to justify why there are errors.  The only legitimate reason I would think of for errors is that the header is internal in *your* library, and was not meant to be used standalone by the user of your library.

If the header is supposed to be used by your clients, do not "fix" the problem by taking the test source file above and adding headers to the source.  You fix it by including the proper headers within (in my simple case) `myheader.h`

Comment: This does NOT imply that the inclusion is necessary. A forward declaration would suffice.

Comment: Right - if a forward declaration within the header gets rid of the compiler error(s), then that is the alternative.

Comment: Can you forward declare `FILE` ? I didn't think so. In particular, it might be declared as `typedef struct __FILE FILE;`.

Comment: @peppe What is the forward declaration of a FILE* (If you don't know the compiler in use) ? (eg. gcc: typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;)

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. I know that my header should compile on its own. The question is *how*? Should I do some fancy `#ifdef`s to find out if the user had already included stdio.h. Should I just include stdio.h and not worry about my clients having conflicts with it? Should I put all I/O-related declarations in a separate header? What else can I do?

Comment: @Matt The standard headers (unless you have an awful compiler) have include guards, so it doesn't make a difference if the user did or did not include the header.

Comment: @Matt there is no need to `#ifdef` - almost all headers contain macros that checks for it. Headers are generally included only once.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: You completely misunderstood me. See my edit to the question.

Comment: @DieterLücking: as I wrote in the other comment above, unfortunately there's no forward declaring header for `FILE`, hence in this particular case inclusion of `stdio.h` is necessary. My comment here was to stress that  to make the header self-contained it would not be strictly necessary to include all the definitions (which is what OP was asking); forward declarations may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the updated question:

Conditionally enabling or disabling blocks of code (or features) depending on order of included files stinks as hell. It's a straight way to hell.

If you want to enable or disable your functionality, making your code more modular, you can use preprocessor macros, possibly requiring user to explicitly choose compilation mode.

```
#ifdef USE_STDIO
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

lotsa lotsa code

#ifdef USE_STDIO
int foo_print(const foo_t *foo);
int foo_fprint(FILE *f, const foo_t *foo);
#endif
```

Downside of this solution: code becomes harder to follow.

Second option is to extract those methods to `foo_io.h` (and possibly `foo_io.c`). The downside of this solution is that you're forcing user to include two files instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

You've already answered your own question. Both 1) and 3) are valid solutions. If you use `FILE*` in one of your functions then it only makes sense to use your function in combination with the header where `FILE` is declared. As others noted, there is no header that would forward declare `FILE`, so your only choice is to include `stdio.h`.

If your client includes your header file, assume that all the functions will be used. Do not use conditional compilation for cutting out include's. If I'd include your header file and see that that it contains a declaration of a function that uses `FILE*` I would expect to have `stdio.h` included as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a standard library functionality, *just include that standard header* full stop. Don't try to over-think that someone may have a function with the same name as something in the standard library: Their code is already fragile/broker and you shouldn't worry about such cases.

I can't make out if your code is C++ or C though (note that even though C++ may have roots in C they are distinct languages). If it's C++ you can use `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h` and use features from the `std` namespace instead of the global namespace. Otherwise if your code is C you have to use `stdio.h`

Comment: Well name conflicts are not the only reason for not including too many header files. My code is neither C nor C++, because it is just an example (although I seem to have made it pretty C-like). I use both languages for various purposes and this is something that comes up with both of them.